# Prices double at checkout Magento - sales_order_flat_quote_address

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, checkout

We are currently experiencing an issue on Magento Community 1.7 where some customers have their totals doubled at checkout.

Investigation has shown that for these customers quotes, they have four entries in the sales_order_flat_quote_address table. This table looks like it should only contain two rows, one for billing and one for shipping.

We are stumped as to why four rows are being created and through vigorous testing cannot find the cause of the issue.

The following test cases have been completed without issue:

1) Create quote and then login. Logout. Create new quote and then login.

2) Ensure no previous quotes for customer. Login. Logout. Add products. Login.

3) Create quote while logged in. Leave logged in. Access seperate browser, add products, login with same customer account.

4) Create quote, login. Open site though proxy / new IP. Add products. Login.

In all the above instances, the issue does not happen.

Has anyone ever had or heard of this issue before?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

We had this issue on enterprise 1.12.  It was very difficult to trace and we raised it with magento who provided a patch.

Are you using OneStepCheckout on your site? Or any other 3rd party modules?

Comment: Could you please enlighten the fix? I'm also experiencing this issue. We use OneStepCheckout. But this is only recently happening, well into our use of that module.

Comment: could you please share the patch or the details please? We also have enterprise but this patch has not been made public

Answer (score 0):

We have had this same issue.

Upon investigation we have determined this to be a problem with the installed theme.

In order to determine this we did the following steps:

1. Create a new fresh Magento instance.
2. Do not add any theme
3. Install a subset of products (or even a single product) to test.
4. Check pricing at checkout.

I have a feeling that the theme developers have used an old base template that contains this bug. Will update this post with more information as I find out more.

Comment: I have the same bug. Do you use Varnish cache server?

Comment: No we weren't using Vanish cache server.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue of duplicate addresses by overwriting `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote::_beforeSave`

```
public function _beforeSave()
{
    $addresses = $this->getAllAddresses();
    if (count($addresses) > 2) {
      for($i = 2; $i < count($addresses); $i++) {
        $address = $addresses[$i];
        $address->isDeleted(true);
      }
    }

    parent::_beforeSave();
}
```

The code deletes any duplicate addresses which cause the cart price to be doubled.

Credit to https://web.archive.org/web/20161230082727/http://www.daveboyce.com/double-order-totals-in-magento/ for the answer.

Comment: does it work on Magento 2 the same way?